# Obtaining the image iterations before final image has been generated StableDiffusionPipeline.pretrained

Tags: python, torch, huggingface, stable-diffusion

I am currently using the `diffusers StableDiffusionPipeline` (from hugging face) to generate AI images with a discord bot which I use with my friends. I was wondering if it was possible to get a preview of the image being generated before it is finished?

For example, if an image takes 20 seconds to generate, since it is using diffusion it starts off blury and gradually gets better and better. What I want is to save the image on each iteration (or every few seconds) and see how it progresses. How would I be able to do this?

```py
class ImageGenerator:
    def __init__(self, socket_listener, pretty_logger, prisma):
        self.model = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5", revision="fp16", torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_auth_token=os.environ.get("HF_AUTH_TOKEN"))
        self.model = self.model.to("cuda")

    async def generate_image(self, data):
        start_time = time.time()
        with autocast("cuda"):
            image = self.model(data.description, height=self.default_height, width=self.default_width,
                               num_inference_steps=self.default_inference_steps, guidance_scale=self.default_guidance_scale)
            image.save(...)
```

The code I have currently is this, however it only returns the image when it is completely done. I have tried to look into how the image is generated inside of the StableDiffusionPipeline but I cannot find anywhere where the image is generated. If anybody could provide any pointers/tips on where I can begin that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the callback argument of the stable diffusion pipeline to get the latent space representation of the image: [link to documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/api/pipelines/stable_diffusion/text2img#diffusers.StableDiffusionPipeline.__call__.callback)

The [implementation](https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/blob/24895a1f494062d73028e31880c8848c6a674750/src/diffusers/pipelines/stable_diffusion/pipeline_stable_diffusion.py#L436) shows how the latents are converted back to an image. We just have to copy that code and decode the latents.

Here is a small example that saves the generated image every 5 steps:

```
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
import torch

#load model
model = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5", revision="fp16", torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_auth_token="YOUR TOKEN HERE")
model = model.to("cuda")

def callback(iter, t, latents):
    # convert latents to image
    with torch.no_grad():
        latents = 1 / 0.18215 * latents
        image = model.vae.decode(latents).sample

        image = (image / 2 + 0.5).clamp(0, 1)

        # we always cast to float32 as this does not cause significant overhead and is compatible with bfloa16
        image = image.cpu().permute(0, 2, 3, 1).float().numpy()

        # convert to PIL Images
        image = model.numpy_to_pil(image)

        # do something with the Images
        for i, img in enumerate(image):
            img.save(f"iter_{iter}_img{i}.png")

# generate image (note the `callback` and `callback_steps` argument)
image = model("tree", callback=callback, callback_steps=5)
```

To understand the stable diffusion model I highly recommend [this](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-stable-diffusion/) blog post.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is insanely helpful, really appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome response, thank you a lot!

Comment: Are we sure of the accuracy of the "Update December 2023" bit? My extremely limited understanding is that line isn't the addition of noise, rather, it's where we update the latents using the predicted noise residual. My read of it is that line is the first time the latent is updated in the iteration, so I don't think it's sensical to call the callback any earlier.

Comment: @DanielPapasian Oh I think you are right. I’ll remove the section again.